# Mongoose bulkWrite - Wrong type for 'q'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkinsert

For my test suite, I want to bulkWrite test info in the database, and then bulk delete any of the test info entered throughout the test to come back to a clean slate. I do so by running a bulkWrite on the db to which I pass the content of a JSON file loaded via nodeJS's require statement.

The problem is that for the dataset

```
[ { deleteOne: { username: 'test-author' } } ]
```

passed to `models[key].collection.bulkWrite(action[key])`, where key is the name of the model of interest and action is the JSON file,I get the following error:

```
{ MongoError: Wrong type for 'q'. Expected a object, got a null.
    at Function.MongoError.create (/var/www/website/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at /var/www/website/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
    at authenticateStragglers (/var/www/website/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/var/www/website/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/website/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:339:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Wrong type for \'q\'. Expected a object, got a null.',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Wrong type for \'q\'. Expected a object, got a null.',
  code: 14,
  codeName: 'TypeMismatch' }
```

I have done some research and have been unable to find a solution to this problem. The error itself is pretty meaningless, so I can't grasp much out of it. Any idea how to solve the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: json file doesn't have model name, so it throw null value.

Comment: could you post some sample data in order to reproduce the problem

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A: Do I have to pass the model name? Cause in the end the call `models[key].collection.bulkWrite(action[key])` resolves to `Author.collection.bulkWrite(action.Author)` - thus I'd suspect that collection is scoped to the Author model

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger You can find the model [here](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/28ed2a32ea6b0a83137e749a085262a3d464469f/server/models/author.js), the data [here](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/28ed2a32ea6b0a83137e749a085262a3d464469f/server/test/tests/uploader/insert.json), the query code [here](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/28ed2a32ea6b0a83137e749a085262a3d464469f/server/test/common/database.js) (lol please don't mind the logs - we all have these moments).

Comment: Have you tried moving module.exports to below your function definition? Sometimes JSON parsing returns the first letter ("u" of undefined) in the case of a weird error. You're may be to do with the module.exports={query:query} before query is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I tried it to no avail. Normally this shouldn't have any impact however, as Javascript does what we call [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), effectively allowning use of functions declared below the current line.

Comment: This being said, by doing some more printing I realized that Model.collection.bulkWrite does not return a promise as explained in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite), nor does it call the callback. So there is definitely something wrong there. Trying Model.bulkWrite directly like shown in the docs returns TypeError: not a function, and trying to use a [callback rather than promises](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/d75d1ff78c713baee56c541e64eaf786925f944e/server/test/common/database.js) still doesn't work.

Comment: I also updated the [test file](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/d75d1ff78c713baee56c541e64eaf786925f944e/server/test/tests/uploader/test.js)

Comment: Alright, I'm a bit appalled by what I just found - Mongoose doesn't throw when it doesn't have any successful connection to a DB. For some reason it seems like the IP of my mongodb docker image is fluctuating, and Mongoose doesn't pick up on whether or not it has an active connection. That explains why no promise nor callback were called. Now I'm back to the same issue of the q => null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MongoDB API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-deleteonemany), the `deleteOne`, `deleteMany`, `updateOne`, `updateMany`, `replaceOne`, and `replaceMany` operation requires to have a property `filter` which acts as the filter for the query.

However [Mongoose's API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) shows the following (mistaken) example:

```
Character.bulkWrite([
  ...
  {
    deleteOne: {
      { name: 'Eddard Stark' }
    }
  }
]).then(handleResult);
```

Hence, the data sent over changes from:

```
[{
  "deleteOne": { "username": "test-author" }
}]
```

to

```
[{
  "deleteOne": { "filter": { "username": "test-author" }} 
}]
```

I'll make sure to pass the message along to the mongoosejs dev group.